# cfstoredproc call not showing runtime values in SQL SERVER profiler

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-profiler

If I do a

```
<cfset arg1 = 'test'>
<cfquery> exec sp_mine #arg1# </cfquery>
```

Profiler shows the correct value I passed into `arg1` at runtime.

e.g:

```
 EXEC sp_mine 'test'
```

I get the same (desired) behavior if I use CFQUERY with a queryparam:

```
<cfset arg1 = 'test'>
<cfquery datasource="dsn" name="out">
    { CALL sp_mine( <cfqueryparam value = "#arg1#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">) }
</cfquery>
```

But If I replace with CFSTOREDPROC:

```
<cfset arg1 = 'test'>
<cfstoredproc datasource="dsn" procedure="sp_mine" >
   <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@arg1" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#arg1#"  >
   <cfprocresult name="out">
</cfstoredproc>
```

I get:

```
EXEC sp_mine @arg1 = @P1
```

I am profiling the following events:

[image]

(EDIT)Here is the exact profile details(small irrelevant change,passing 1 instead of 'test')

[image]

**Enviroment:**

I am using :

- Coldfusion 11,0,05,293506
- SQL Server 2014

Comment: Isn't that just telling you the value's being passed as a parameter rather than a hard-coded value? Is the proc not actually doing what you want it to?

Comment: To verify Adam's thought, do the first one again with a query parameter.

Comment: +AdamCameron Have edited my answer to include an example with query param, the profiler shows the correct runtime value. I want to know why it doesnt do the same with CFSTOREDPROC? The sproc does what I want it to do in all cases , im only interested in why the profiler is picking up the real values if I use CFQUERY.

Comment: (Edit) Unless you are saying the end result of the procedure call is different, then it is not that the profiler is not "picking up the real value" ... but is simply displaying them differently depending on how the procedure was invoked ie PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, etcetera. If that is the issue, you need to look at the Profiler's documentation for an explanation of how it displays procedure parameters for the different events.

Comment: @Leigh the sproc returns the same result in all 3 ways of calling it (not sure why that has any bearing on this question). "look at the Profiler's documentation for an explanation of how it displays procedure parameters for the different events." - Thanks Leigh but I have done this and not been able to solve my problem, hence Im posting here. I have listed the events that Im profiling, If you know which event I need to add, please let me know.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar - The reason for asking was that the actual issue was not 100% clear. I *thought* RPC:Completed or SP:Completed would display the param value, but  I do not have access to SQL Profiler to verify it at the moment. A) You mentioned tracing several events, specifically which of those event(s) gave the three (3) results above? B) Any difference if you drop the `dbvarname="@arg1"` and rely on positional notation?

Comment: @Leigh edited post with screenshot of actual results. Positional notation doesnt make a difference. I also found another difference between cfquery/cfstoredproc, posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807673/cfdump-different-for-cfquery-vs-cfstoredproc

Comment: @SajjanSarkar - Well, how CF chooses to display the executed sql for debugging is another story (and out of our control).  You could always enable logging, which is *very* detailed (though probably more granular than you want in this case).  Unfortunately, I do not recall how the Profiler displays values for PreparedStatements vs CallableStatements. Though FWIW, a quick search turned up other threads mentioning similar difficulties, so it is probably not specific to CF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**
Ok, I found a way to do this FWIW. I feel this is much better than logging/dumping on the client side as it is silent and non-intrusive and can be done even on prod environments.But each to his own.

When using CFSTOREDPROC, the arguments are set positionally by a call to `sp_execute`. So profiling this as well as your sproc will get you what you need.

**Example:**

**CF:**

[image]

**Profiler Events:**

[image]

**Profiler Filters:**

[image]

**Output (after your CF code runs):**

[image]