# CFDUMP different for CFQUERY vs CFSTOREDPROC

Tags: coldfusion

Problem:

I have a sproc which I am calling in 2 ways (cfquery and cfstoredproc) and then dumping the resultsets. I am passing in the same argument in both cases and the sproc returns a trivial hard-coded result for this test. When i dump the results,
I can see the actual query SQL in the cfquery call but not in the cfstoredproc call.Why? I would like to use the cfstoredproc version but want the ability to get the SQL attribute of the dump like in CFQUERY.

*(Yes, I know there is something different in the way CF prepares the statement etc, I want to know exactly what.)*

**CF Code:**

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="tc" procedure="sp_dumptest" >
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@arg1" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="1"  >
    <!--- Out variable --->
    <cfprocresult name="out1">
</cfstoredproc>
<cfdump var="#out1#" label="with cfstoredproc">

<cfquery name="out2" datasource="tc" >
{call sp_dumptest (1) }
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#out2#" label="with cfquery">
```

**Output:**

[image]

**(EDIT after Adam's answer)**

I tried adding a result attribute and a fetchclientInfo, but it still wont give the actual SQL. Here is what is dumped when I dump the RESULT variable.

```
<cfstoredproc   datasource="Timecurrent" 
                procedure="sp_dumptest" 
                result="rsx" 
                debug="true" 
                fetchClientInfo="yes">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@arg1" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="1"  >
    <!--- Out variable --->
    <cfprocresult name="out1">
</cfstoredproc>
<cfdump var="#rsx#" label="with cfstoredproc">
```

[image]

**Environment:**

- Coldfusion 11,0,05,293506
- SQL Server 2014

Comment: When you make a call to a stored proc, there is no way, during the execution of the proc that you can determine what SQL is being executed. It is, essentially, a 'black box'. You pass data in, you get data back.

Comment: Why is knowing what SQL is run important? What is the use case for needing this information? In over 10 years as a developer, I have never had a case where this was needed.

Comment: Technically.. in the first (cfstoredproc) you are dumping the result.  In the second (cfquery) you are dumping the query object.  Those would be different and not have the same content.

Comment: I'm curious about how you find `{call sp_dumptest (1) }` to constitute useful information.

Comment: I find it useful to debug, to find out what arguments were passed to the sproc. This is ONLY for debugging. Given that the SQL SERVER profiler also does not show the actual values passed in to the sproc if you use CFSTOREDPROC, this was one way I was hoping to see the argument values without having to manually print. @ScottStroz

Comment: in this case it looks trivial because i have directly passed in 1, but in reality it would be a dynamic variable. So I want to know what was passed in. With CFQUERY u CAN see the SQL Scott.

Comment: When I'm presented with that situation, I just output or dump the variable.

Comment: @DanBracuk right. Unfortunately in our application (which ive inherited) there are sprocs with sometimes 25 arguments which get set with conditional values. These were previously CFQUERY calls but that was not very readable as they ended up as 25 comma separated var names and depended on the dev being diligent on adding comments to describe the arg name. I have been trying to replace the CFQUERY calls with CFSTOREDPROC calls but looks like to debug the runtime call now, i will have to manually dump 25 vars as opposed to the (elegant ?) cfdump that works with CFQUERY.

Comment: Type them into a list and output them inside a loop.  My personal style is that if I am debugging ColdFusion logic, I do so without a trip to the database.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave said: you're comparing apples with oranges.

In the first example you are dumping out just the value of the `out` param returned by the proc. You'd only expect to see the value in there.

In the second example you are dumping the result of an entire `<cfquery>` call, which includes the result, as well as the SQL statement and params that were passed to JDBC and various other bits and bobs.

What happens if you give your `<cfstoredproc>` call a `result` attribute, and dump `that` out? You ought not expect to see the *same* sort of metadata - it's still apples and oranges - but it would be more likely to have additional details.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that previously I was dumping the proc result variable. However dumping the RESULT variable doesnt show the SQL either (along with the.. err.. result)

Comment: As I said, you would be able to get the SQL executed in a stored procedure. it is like asking to get the code that is run when you all `isArray()` in ColdFusion...you simply cannot. What is the use case for needing this information?

Comment: @ScottStroz I could see a case for the metadata to return what was sent to the DB, eg the proc name and the param values. That is what the `<cfquery>` metadata is: it's not explicitly the *SQL*, it's the statement that gets sent to the DB (which happens to be an SQL string and params, if you see the distinction I'm trying to make). However you are right that there should not be any expectation that the code from the proc should be returned. That makes no sense whatsoever.